# makefile include path hierarchy and lib location?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I have a standard installed debian dev package which has an include file held e.g.

```
/usr/include/abcd.h
```

But I have an updated package compiled from source which has the include file as e.g.

```
/home/user01/include/abcd.h
```

How do I get either command line gcc or in a make file make sure it picks up the latter?

If I add either

```
gcc -I /home/user01/include
```

or
in the make file alter the includes line to have

```
INCLUDES = -I /home/user01/include
```

It appears to always take the one held in /usr/include first?

I had tried to keep it simple, but as per @MadScientist request here is more actual detail.

The following builds, no warnings or errors but the result of running indicates that it is using the old repo based version of mdbtools not the one I have compiled from source and utility programs within that run as expected with fixes. (on Debian 11)

```
gcc -g -O2 -DSQL -Wall -Werror -DUNIXODBC -o myTestMdb main.c -I /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/include/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo/ -I /usr/include/pango-1.0/ -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include/ -I /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/ -I /usr/include/atk-1.0/ -lmdb -lglib-2.0 -lmdbsql -DHAVE_GLIB
```

If I try (as suggested adding the -nostdinc)

```
gcc -g -O2 -DSQL -Wall -Werror -DUNIXODBC -o myTestMdb main.c -nostdinc -I /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/include/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo/ -I /usr/include/pango-1.0/ -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include/ -I /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/ -I /usr/include/atk-1.0/ -lmdb -lglib-2.0 -lmdbsql -DHAVE_GLIB
```

I get

```
main.c:20:10: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
```

20 | #include <string.h>

if I try

```
gcc -g -O2 -DSQL -Wall -Werror -DUNIXODBC -o myTestMdb main.c -nostdinc -I /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/include/ -I /usr/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo/ -I /usr/include/pango-1.0/ -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include/ -I /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/ -I /usr/include/atk-1.0/ -lmdb -lglib-2.0 -lmdbsql -DHAVE_GLIB
```

I get

```
/usr/include/string.h:26:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
```

26 | #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>

Likewise if I try to use make and have in the makdefile

```
INCLUDES = -I /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo/ -I /usr/include/pango-1.0/ -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include/ -I /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/ -I /usr/include/atk-1.0/ -I /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools/include/ -I /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools/include/
```

I get

```
/usr/include/mdbtools.h:37:10: fatal error: mdbfakeglib.h: No such file or directory
```

37 | #include <mdbfakeglib.h>

Note the /usr/include/mdbtools.h  NOT the desired  /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/include/mdbtools.h which I have checked the folder that header file does exist there

so as per @G.M. suggestion I added the -H -P to the build this showed it was using the mdbtools.h (and other mdb related .h files) from where wanted. So the /usr/include/mdbtools.h was specific to a makefile issue. will leave that for now.

So now I think it is lib related I've only been using -lmdb -lmdbsql if I do a whereis I get the /usr/lib entries.
How do I make it use a different location I tried?

```
-L /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/sql/ -L /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/libmdb/ -lmdb -lmdbsql
```

or

```
-L /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/sql/.libs -L /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/libmdb/.libs -lmdb -lmdbsql
```

But it would still appear to use the /usr based ones from the output I get.

as per @G.M. tried adding -Wl -verbose  but got

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wl’; did you mean ‘-W’?

gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-verbose’; did you mean ‘--verbose’?
```

for reference gcc version is

```
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
```

I reran with --verbose but I don't see any greater detail on where it is looking for mdbsql or libmdbsql.so from the -lmdbsql parameter which I hope should use from -L/media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/sql/.libs/ where it does exist but from output of built program I doubt.

Still have the makefile related issue to look into but the command line issue was my confusion on shared and static library.
I tried a "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/sql/.libs/:...etc " which did not work but an "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/sql/.libs/: ... etc" did work as desired

Comment: maybe ... if I hand feed all of the other needed includes e.g. the gcc fails with fatal error on #include <string.h> ... and if then provide -I /usr/include as a latter parameter it fails on the next thing .... the ideal is to be able to nominate override(s) but allow defaults as fallback. Not sure where I would put -nostdinc into the makefile and assume it would have same issue(s).

Comment: The behavior you describe can't happen so there's something you're doing that you didn't describe here.  If you add `-I/foo` to the compile line all headers will be searched for in `/foo` before any system directories.  Please show the exact include line you have, the exact compile line you run, and the errors you get.

Comment: edit original to add detail

Comment: The idea of adding -nostdinc is definitely not right: don't do that.  That's only useful if you're trying to build a kernel module or some other system that doesn't use ANY of the system libraries.

Comment: If it doesn't work from the command line there's no use trying to make it work from a makefile; make just runs the same command that you would run by hand.

Comment: It's still not clear from your message which headers specifically are problematic.  What is the `#include` in your source file, which is not getting the right version?  If it's `mdbtools.h`, what happens if you run `ls /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/include/mdbtools.h`?

Comment: sorry thought I had made that clear the mdbtools.h file does exist in /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/include/
And should be the one being picked up and references to the lib files should make use of the files under /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/ but is clear when it does build that the test program is still making use of the repo based mdbtools in /usr/... rather than the  /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/

Comment: Does your `mdbtools.h` have exactly the same header guard as the system supplied one?  If not then it's possible both are being included via various `#include ...` chains.  If you add the `-H -P` flags to your compile command the output should tell you exactly what is being `#include`d and from where.

Comment: @G.M. thank you that has confirmed the build from command line is using the correct include files so now looking at where the lib files are pointing to. See update in initial question.

Comment: This stuff is really pretty straightforward: it just adds the library name to the path you provided.  There's no magic here.  If you say `-L /foo` then the libraries will be looked for as files in `/foo`.  That's it.  The thing you aren't telling us is what the actual, complete pathname is of the library you're trying to link.  Without this info we can't say what the right/wrong flags are.

Comment: I believe I am trying to point libmdbsql.so which is in the folder /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/sql/.libs/ ...

Comment: Again, you can use compiler/linker flags to determine what is being looked for and where.  If you compile and link in a single step using `gcc` you can add the flag `-Wl,-verbose` and the linker will output a lot (an *awful* lot) of useful information.

Comment: @G.M. thankyou see main body, got errors with -Wl -verbose

Comment: Did you use the flag exactly as specified: `-Wl,-verbose` -- *with* the comma and *without* any spaces?

Comment: @G.M. oops sorry yes missed the comma and no spaces. I can then see it is using what I want with response in log
attempt to open /media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/sql/.libs//libmdbsql.so succeeded
/media/sdd02/src/mdbtools-deb11/src/sql/.libs//libmdbsql.so
so now not sure, will have revisit